# Adding extra lines to document using awk

Tags: bash, shell, jsp, awk, sed

I have a jsp page and a fucntion in it.

```
function foo() {
if(confirm("bar") {
    // do something
}
```

I want to edit the exsiting or add a new if condtion to the jsp page with a shell script to make it like below

```
function foo() {
if(confirm("new text"+bar) {
   //do something 
}
```

I'm trying to use awk like this to a new if condition when one doesnt exist already.

```
awk '/foo/{print;print "if(confirm(Hey) {";next}1' myjsp.jsp
awk '/foo2/{print "}";}1' myjsp.jsp  //foo2 is fucntion after foo. using this add closing }
```

The problem is I'm seeing a duplicate lines printing I guess because option 1 print out everything after current line. How do I stop this.

Comment: your `if...` statement has error... unpaired `)`

Comment: yeah. that's just me missing it in question. It's fine in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method

```
sed -r '/foo()/{n;/if\(confirm/s/([^"]+)"(.*)".*/\1"new text"+\2)\{/}' fileName
```

**OutPut:**

```
function foo() {
if(confirm("new text"+bar){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I also need to add if condition myself it doesn't exists. So that's what I was using the awk for. The problem is first awk adds and prints all next lines. second awk print closing }. I think a workaround is just use first awk and on the output of it use second awk. But is there any elegent solution ? btw I'm new to awk/sed, trying to understand your solution.